# How to style pagination in ng-table v4.0.0 using bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-4, ngtable

I'm using ng-table v0.8.3 for the ng-table.min.js file. While i'm using ng-table v4.0.0 for the ng-table.min.css file. But still the pagination design is not working see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhU2U.png) picture. The pagenumbers have no design and are close to each other. I got the .scss file in this link: https://github.com/jrbotros/ng-table/blob/master/src/styles/ng-table.scss, and i just converted it to a css file to include in my index.html using this online converter : http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/. And it generates this code below:

```
.ng-table th {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.ng-table th.sortable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator {
  padding-right: 18px;
  position: relative;
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:after, .ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before {
  content: "";
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent;
  visibility: visible;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
}
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:hover:after, .ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc, .ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc {
  background-color: rgba(141, 192, 219, 0.25);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after, .ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:after {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:before, .ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:before {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:after, .ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.ng-table th.filter .input-filter {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-header th {
  text-align: left;
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-selector {
  display: block;
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-close, .ng-table .ng-table-group-toggle {
  float: right;
}
.ng-table .ng-table-group-toggle {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .ng-table-responsive {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive td:before {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive thead tr th {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive thead tr.ng-table-filters th {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive thead tr.ng-table-filters th form > div {
    padding: 8px;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive td {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .ng-table-responsive td:before {
    content: attr(data-title-text);
  }
  .ng-table-responsive, .ng-table-responsive thead, .ng-table-responsive tbody, .ng-table-responsive th, .ng-table-responsive td, .ng-table-responsive tr {
    display: block;
  }
}
.ng-table-pagination {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.ng-table-group-selector:before, .ng-table-group-selector:after, .filter:before, .filter:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.ng-table-group-selector:after, .filter:after {
  clear: both;
}
.filter > .filter-cell {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.filter-horizontal > .filter-cell {
  padding: 0 2px;
}
.filter-horizontal > .filter-cell:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.filter-horizontal > .filter-cell:last-child, .filter-horizontal > .filter-cell.last {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.s12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.s11 {
  width: 91.66667%;
}
.s10 {
  width: 83.33333%;
}
.s9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.s8 {
  width: 66.66667%;
}
.s7 {
  width: 58.33333%;
}
.s6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.s5 {
  width: 41.66667%;
}
.s4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
.s3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.s2 {
  width: 16.66667%;
}
.s1 {
  width: 8.33333%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 468px) {
  .s12, .s11, .s10, .s9, .s8, .s7, .s6, .s5, .s4, .s3, .s2, .s1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .filter > .filter-cell {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

However if i use bootstrap v.3.3.7 i got the pagination design, but i want to use bootstrap4 because my UI got destroyed if i use the older version of bootstrap.

Comment: looking for this ? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/pagination/

Comment: Where will i put the class="pagination" if i'm using a <table> ? @IsmailFarooq

Comment: you have to use outside the table

Answer (score 0):

You need update css classes to pagination in the ngTable.js

the line 2218 `$templateCache.put('ng-table/pager.html', '<div class="ng-cloak ng-table-pager" ng-if="params.data.length"> <div ng-if="params.settings().counts.length" class="ng-table-counts btn-group pull-right"> <button ng-repeat="count in params.settings().counts" type="button" ng-class="{\'active\':params.count()==count}" ng-click="params.count(count)" class="btn btn-default"> <span ng-bind="count"></span> </button> </div> <ul ng-if="pages.length" class="pagination ng-table-pagination"> <li ng-class="{\'disabled\': !page.active && !page.current, \'active\': page.current}" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-switch="page.type"> <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&laquo;</a> <a ng-switch-when="first" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href=""><span ng-bind="page.number"></span></a> <a ng-switch-when="page" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href=""><span ng-bind="page.number"></span></a> <a ng-switch-when="more" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&#8230;</a> <a ng-switch-when="last" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href=""><span ng-bind="page.number"></span></a> <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&raquo;</a> </li> </ul> </div> ');`

with this `$templateCache.put('ng-table/pager.html', '<div class="ng-cloak ng-table-pager" ng-if="params.data.length"> <div ng-if="params.settings().counts.length" class="ng-table-counts btn-group pull-right"> <button ng-repeat="count in params.settings().counts" type="button" ng-class="{\'active\':params.count()==count}" ng-click="params.count(count)" class="btn btn-light"> <span ng-bind="count"></span> </button> </div> <ul ng-if="pages.length" class="pagination ng-table-pagination"> <li ng-class="{\'disabled\': !page.active && !page.current, \'active\': page.current, \'page-item\': !page.current || page.current || !page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-switch="page.type"> <a class="page-link" ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&laquo;</a> <a class="page-link" ng-switch-when="first" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href=""><span ng-bind="page.number"></span></a> <a class="page-link" ng-switch-when="page" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href=""><span ng-bind="page.number"></span></a> <a class="page-link" ng-switch-when="more" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&#8230;</a> <a class="page-link" ng-switch-when="last" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href=""><span ng-bind="page.number"></span></a> <a class="page-link" ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&raquo;</a> </li> </ul> </div> ');`

and the line

the javascript file take as reference is https://github.com/jrbotros/ng-table/blob/master/dist/ng-table.js